# Using google analytics for my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, google-analytics

I have a native iPhone app that is really only a UIWebView of a web application.  I am planning on including google web analytics on the web app to track how mobile app users are using the application.

Are there any issues with this that you can see?  Of course I won't get crash data, but I'm only looking for the number of UU's, page views, and clicks off the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics for web should do fine. The problem is if your app is just an UIWebView, it'll probably be reject by Apple.